# Does GHashIO already have above 51% hashrate?

Tags: mining-pools, security

Right before writing this question I noticed the GHashIO showing 32% hashrate distribution using the [following link](https://blockchain.info/pools).

Unknown has 26%. And the IP address of the most blocks reported from unknown is: 88.150.205.243. After doing some digging it seems that the [IP address is owned by GhashIO](http://totalhash.com/network/ip:88.150.205.243) according to [totalhash](http://www.totalhash.com).

Not sure how reliable the data from [totalhash](http://www.totalhash.com) is but it seems that GHashIO has already achieved above 51% total hashrate. Can someone confirm this? If it's false then what would be the proper way to investigate this in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When blockchain.info says that a block came from an IP address (for example, 88.150.205.243) it means that blockchain.info received this block from this IP address, but it can not determine which pool mined this block.

It also means that blockchain.info is connected with this peer node. There is a high probability that this node has many peers where blocks can come from.

It does not mean that this block was mined by this IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The operator also said that if he gets close to 51%, he'll pull everyone mining on the Getwork protocol, which will reduce their rate by about 10%.

Comment: Have you a source for this?

Comment: And even if he says he'll do this, doesn't make it reliable and trustworthy. The first honest criminal should still be born imho.

Comment: I can't remember where I read that, it was a while back.