# Which pooled mining scheme is better in terms of constant mining?

Tags: mining-reward, mining-pools

I'm comparing gash.io with slush scheme. Say I mine 24x7 without pool hopping at 5GH/s. Will the BTC amount be the same if I mine at slush or gash.io. And what if I get disconnected from either of pools for say random one half hour duration or more a day, how would the reward be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will roughly (~1%) be the same, otherwise no-one would stay at Slush or GHash.IO, if one of them has obvious lower rewards. In your previous [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/is-there-any-difference-in-pool-mining-with-gash-io-over-slush) I answered that there are differences in the way your share is calculated, and thus the reward changes. But because you don't want to hop pools, `score` will be the same as `PPLNS`. Otherwise you can try to mine a week in both pools, and see the reward you get in both pools. I think it is best to try it yourself. You get bitcoin in return, so it is not for nothing.

I'm not sure how the disconnection works with the `score`-system, but I think `PPLNS` wins on that area, because you won't get penalised. IN `PPLNS` you'll just get paid for each share you contribute. So if you mine 100 shares/hour, and you are offline 6 hours, you'll miss 600 shares. Depending on the btc/share, that exact amount of btc is what you miss during your offline time.

Answer (score 1):

The method used in slush's pool is not completely hopping-proof, so if hoppers exist in the pool, your earnings will be slightly reduced.

However, contrary to a popular myth, slush's method does not "penalize" you for disconnecting. On average, you'll lose exactly the worth of the missed work during the time you were disconnected. Your variance will be higher though.

In general, any hopping-proof method will work, regardless of your mining pattern.

More information about reward methods can be found in [Analysis of Bitcoin Pooled Mining Reward Systems](https://bitcoil.co.il/pool_analysis.pdf).